# Javascript not rendering conditional statements - Django Project

Tags: javascript, html, django, jquery-file-upload

Currently am building a file that is based on [older Django version](https://github.com/miki725/Django-jQuery-File-Uploader-Integration-demo) of Blueimp's jQuery File Upload. Working multiple bugs as I 1.) learn and 2.) bring it up to Django version 3.0.8. I can click on "Add Files", choose my file and then it will show some information on the screen as shown. The only item that renders correctly is the file size and the `open_tv` and `close_tv` variables. The rest of the JavaScript is verbatim from the code. I am unable to determine the fix for this.

```
Output

    ${name} 11.66 KB    Error: {{if error === 'maxFileSize'}}File is too big {{else error === 'minFileSize'}}File is too small {{else error === 'acceptFileTypes'}}Filetype is not allowed {{else error === 'maxNumberOfFiles'}}Max number of files exceeded {{else}}${error} {{/if}}
```

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import RequestAttachment, ServiceRequest
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.conf import settings
import os

def esr_submit(request):
    # used to generate random unique id
    import uuid

    # settings for the file upload
    # you can define other parameters here and check validity late in the code
    options = {
        # maximum file size (must be in bytes)
        "maxfilesize": 10 * 2 ** 20,  # 10 mb
        # minimum file size (must be in bytes)
        "minfilesize": 1 * 2 ** 10,  # 1 kb
        # the file types which are going to be allowed for upload
        # must be in mimetype (now content type)
        "acceptedformats": (
            "image/jpeg",
            "image/png",
            "image/gif",
            "application/pdf",
            "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
            "application/msword",
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        )
    }

    # POST request
    # meaning user has triggered an upload action
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # figure out the path where the files will be uploaded to
        # BASE_DIR is from the settings file
        temp_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "tmp")

        # if 'f' query parameter is not specified, then a file is being uploaded
        if not ("f" in request.GET.keys()):  # upload file

            # make sure some files have been uploaded
            if not request.FILES:
                return HttpResponseBadRequest('Must upload a file.')

            # make sure unique id is specified - VERY IMPORTANT
            # this is necessary because of the following:
            #       We want users to upload to a unique directory
            #       however, the uploader will make independent requests to the server to upload each file,
            #       so, there has to be a method for all these files to be recognized as a single batch of files
            #       A unique id for each session will do the job

            if not request.POST.get("uid"):
                return HttpResponseBadRequest("UID not specified.")
            uid = request.POST.get("uid")
            print(uid)
            # update the temporary path by creating a sub-folder within the upload folder with the uid name
            temp_path = os.path.join(temp_path, uid)

            # get the uploaded file
            file = request.FILES.get['files[]']

            # initialize the error
            # If error occurs, this will have the string error message
            # so the uploader can display the appropriate message
            error = False

            # check against options for errors

            # file size
            if file.size > options["maxfilesize"]:
                error = "maxFileSize"
            if file.size < options["minfilesize"]:
                error = "minFileSize"
            # allowed file type
            if file.content_type not in options["acceptedformats"]:
                error = "acceptFileTypes"

            # the response data which will be returned to the uploader as json
            response_data = {
                "name": file.name,
                "size": file.size,
                "type": file.content_type
            }

            # if there was an error, add error message to response_data and return
            if error:
                # append error message
                response_data["error"] = error
                # generate json
                response_data = JsonResponse([response_data])
                # return response to uploaded with error so it can display the error message
                return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type='application/json')

            # make temporary dir if none exists already
            if not os.path.exists(temp_path):
                os.makedirs(temp_path)

            # get the absolute path of where the uploaded file will be saved
            # add some random data to the filename in order to avoid conflicts
            # when two files with same name are uploaded
            filename = os.path.join(temp_path, '(' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + ')' + ' ' + file.name)
            # open the file handler with write binary code
            destination = open(filename, "wb+")
            # save file data into the disk
            # use the chunk method in case the file is too big in order to not clutter system memory
            for chunk in file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
                # close the file
            destination.close()

            # here you can add the file to a database, move it around, do anything
            # if you do move the file around, make sure to update the delete_url which will be
            # sent to the server or not include that information at all in the response.
            # // This will be where the file will be moved from temp to the database upon submittal of the esr form
            # or when the esr is saved as draft //

            # allows to generate properly formatted and escaped url queries

            import urllib.parse
            # url for deleting the file in case the user decides to delete it
            response_data["delete_url"] = request.path + "?" + urllib.parse.urlencode(
                {"f": uid + "/" + os.path.split(filename)[1]}
            )
            # specify the delete type - must be POST for csrf
            response_data["delete_type"] = "POST"

            # generate the json data
            response_data = JsonResponse([response_data], safe=False)
            # response type
            response_type = "application/json"

            # QUIRK HERE
            # in jQuery uploader, when it falls back to uploading using iFrames,
            # the response content type has to be text/html
            # if json wil be sent, error will occur
            # if iFrames is sending the request, it's headers are a little different compared
            # to the jQuery AJAX request
            # They have different sets of HTT_ACCEPT values
            # so if the text/html is present, the file was uploaded using iFrame because
            # that value is not in the set when uploaded by XHR
            if "text/html" in request.META["HTTP_ACCEPT"]:
                response_type = "text/html"

            # return the data to the uploading plugin
            print(response_data)
            print(response_type)
            return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type=response_type)

        else:  # file has to be deleted from the temp dir

            # get the file path by getting it from the query (e.g. '?f=filename.here')
            filepath = os.path.join(temp_path, request.GET["f"])

            # make sure the file exists
            # if not return error
            if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
                return HttpResponseBadRequest("File does not exist")

            # delete the file
            # this step might not be a secure method so extra security precautions might have to be taken
            os.remove(filepath)

            # generate true json result
            # in this case is it a json True value
            # if true is not returned, the file will not be removed form the upload queue
            response_data = JsonResponse(True)

            # return the result data here
            # it always has to be json
            return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="application/json")

    else:  # it is a GET method
        context = {
            # the unique id which will be used to get the folder path
            "uid": uuid.uuid4(),
            # these two are necessary to generate the jQuery templates
            # they have to be included here since they conflict with django template system
            "open_tv": '{{',
            "close_tv": '}}',
            # some of the parameters to be checked by javascript
            "maxfilesize": options["maxfilesize"],
            "minfilesize": options["minfilesize"],
        }
        return render(request, "esr_submit/esr_submit_jquery.html", context)
```

```
base.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
{% load static %}


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EG Services - {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!--CDNs
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5a54e295bd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'base/icons/favicon.ico' %}">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> -->

    <!--LOCAL BOOSTRAP, JQUERY AND POPPER AS BACKUP TO CDN-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'js/jqueryUI/jquery-ui.css' %}">
    <!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.fileupload.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css' %}"/>
 <!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
    <noscript
      ><link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.fileupload-noscript.css' %}"/>
    </noscript>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css' %}"/>
    </noscript>

</head>

<body>
...
   <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'css/fontawesome.min.css' %}"></script>
    <script defer src="{% static 'js/all.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/moment.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jqueryUI/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>


    <!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/tmpl.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/load-image.all.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/canvas-to-blob.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- blueimp Gallery script -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/blueimp-gallery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fileupload-process.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fileupload-image.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload audio preview plugin -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload video preview plugin -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fileupload-video.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- The main application script -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/demo.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE 8 and IE 9 -->
    <!--[if (gte IE 8)&(lt IE 10)]
      <script src="{% static 'js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js' %}"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.ui.widget.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
<!--    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>-->
    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/datatables.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#id_due_date" ).datepicker();
        $( "#anim" ).on( "change", function() {
            $( "#id_due_date" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", $( this ).val() );
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>
```

```
esr_submit_jquery.html

{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% block title %}
Submit an ESR
{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload Widget
    // reference https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // this formData is necessary to pass the csrf and pass uid to django
        formData: [
            { name: "uid", value: "{{ uid }}"},
//            { name: "csrfmiddlewaretoken", value: "{{ csrf_token }}"}
        ],
        maxFileSize: {{ maxfilesize }},
        minFileSize: {{ minfilesize }},
        sequentialUploads: true
    });

    // Load existing files
    $.getJSON($('#fileupload form').prop('action'), function (files) {
        var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload');
        fu.adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
        fu.renderDownload(files)
                .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'))
                .fadeIn(function () {
                    // Fix for IE7 and lower:
                    $(this).show();
                });
    });

    // Open the download dialogs via iframes, to prevent aborting current uploads
    $('#fileupload .files a:not([target^_blank])').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<iframe style="display:none;"></iframe>')
                .prop('src', this.href)
                .appendTo('body');
    });
});
</script>

{% block content %}
<div>
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div id="fileupload">
    <form action="{% url 'esr_submit:esr_submit' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i>
                <span>Cancel upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                <span>Delete files</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="fileupload-content">
        <table class="files"></table>
        <div class="fileupload-progressbar"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr class="template-upload{{ open_tv }} if error{{ close_tv }} ui-state-error{{ open_tv }}/if{{ close_tv }}">
        <td class="preview"></td>
        <td class="name">${name}</td>
        <td class="size">${sizef}</td>
        {{ open_tv }}if error{{ close_tv }}
        <td class="error" colspan="2">Error:
            {{ open_tv }}if error === 'maxFileSize'{{ close_tv }}File is too big
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 'minFileSize'{{ close_tv }}File is too small
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 'acceptFileTypes'{{ close_tv }}Filetype is not allowed
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 'maxNumberOfFiles'{{ close_tv }}Max number of files exceeded
            {{ open_tv }}else{{ close_tv }}${error}
            {{ open_tv }}/if{{ close_tv }}
        </td>
        {{ open_tv }}else{{ close_tv }}
        <td class="progress">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="start">
            <button>Start</button>
        </td>
        {{ open_tv }}/if{{ close_tv }}
        <td class="cancel">
            <button>Cancel</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr class="template-download{{ open_tv }} if error{{ close_tv }} ui-state-error{{ open_tv }}/if{{ close_tv }}">
        {{ open_tv }}if error{{ close_tv }}
        <td></td>
        <td class="name">${name}</td>
        <td class="size">${sizef}</td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2">
            {{ open_tv }}if error === 1{{ close_tv }}File exceeds upload_max_filesize (php.ini directive)
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 2{{ close_tv }}File exceeds MAX_FILE_SIZE (HTML form directive
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 3{{ close_tv }}File was only partially uploaded
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 4{{ close_tv }}No file was uploaded
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 5{{ close_tv }}Missing a temporary folder
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 6{{ close_tv }}Failed to write file to disk
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 7{{ close_tv }}File upload stopped by extension
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 'maxFileSize'{{ close_tv }}File is too big
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 'minFileSize'{{ close_tv }}File is too small
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 'acceptFileTypes'{{ close_tv }}Filetype not allowed
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 'maxNumberOfFiles'{{ close_tv }}Max number of files exceeded
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 'uploadedBytes'{{ close_tv }}Uploaded bytes exceed file size
            {{ open_tv }}else error === 'emptyResult'{{ close_tv }}Empty file upload result
            {{ open_tv }}else{{ close_tv }}${error}
            {{ open_tv }}/if{{ close_tv }}
        </td>
        {{ open_tv }}else{{ close_tv }}
        <td class="preview">
            {{ open_tv }}if thumbnail_url{{ close_tv }}
            <a href="${url}" target="_blank"><img src="${thumbnail_url}"></a>
            {{ open_tv }}/if{{ close_tv }}
        </td>
        <td class="name">
            <a href="${url}" {{ open_tv }}if thumbnail_url{{ close_tv }}
               target="_blank"{{ open_tv }}/if{{ close_tv}}>${name}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size">${sizef}</td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        {{ open_tv }}/if{{ close_tv }}
        <td class="delete">
            <button data-type="${delete_type}" data-url="${delete_url}">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
{% endblock content%}
```

```
script.js

/* Enable Django CSRF-ready AJAX calls - directly from the Django docs. Put this code before any jQuery that uses AJAX
 as a catch-all for cross site forgery protection (CSRF)*/

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});

$(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload Widget
    // reference https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // this formData is necessary to pass the csrf and pass uid to django
        formData: [
            { name: "uid", value: "{{ uid }}"},
//            { name: "csrfmiddlewaretoken", value: "{{ csrf_token }}"}
        ],
        maxFileSize: "{{ maxfilesize }}",
        minFileSize: "{{ minfilesize }}",
        sequentialUploads: true
    });

    // Load existing files
    $.getJSON($('#fileupload form').prop('action'), function (files) {
        var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload');
        fu.adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
        fu.renderDownload(files)
                .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'))
                .fadeIn(function () {
                    // Fix for IE7 and lower:
                    $(this).show();
                });
    });

    // Open the download dialogs via iframes, to prevent aborting current uploads
    $('#fileupload .files a:not([target^_blank])').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<iframe style="display:none;"></iframe>')
                .prop('src', this.href)
                .appendTo('body');
    });
});
```